# One div's checkbox input affecting another div's checkbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am using basic HTML to create two different divs, each having some checkboxes as options.(Basically I'm creating a test module). I have checked some checkboxes of the first div. Now, when I go to the second div, and click on the text i.e the label of some checkboxes, the corresponding checkboxes of the first div are getting unchecked. This should not happen. Please help me out

Sorry guys. Did not post the code.                                                                             These are two different divs
First One:

```
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="csuite_2" id="opB" value="B">
            <label class="form-check-label" >
              Daily
            </label>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="csuite_2" id="opC" value="C">
            <label class="form-check-label" >
              Once a month
            </label>
          </div>
```

Second One

```
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="expectation_3" id="opB" value="B">
            <label class="form-check-label" >
              Fund Manager
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="expectation_3" id="opD" value="D">
            <label class="form-check-label" >
              Launching my own startup
            </label>
          </div>
          <br/>
```

I have tried not wrapping the label to the checkbox and it works fine. But is there a way I can do it by wrapping the label and stopping this thing from happening?

Comment: Please show us your html and other relevant code, else we can't tell you whats wrong

Comment: without code how it can be possible to help?

Comment: must be a copy paste issue, where you would have given same value of "for" attribute to other labels as well.

Comment: please post the code

Comment: it seems you have wrapped label for the complete div, so it is checking first div checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your problem.

Basically its because of the similar `id` & `for`.

As you can see in the below code I have used Bike & Car as `id`  in "div1" and the same id's are being used in the "div2". So make sure to give a unique id and corresponding for values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="div1">
 <label for="Bike">
     <input id="Bike" type="checkbox"> I have a bike
    </label><br>
   <label for="Car">
     <input id="Car" type="checkbox"> I have a car
    </label><br>
<div>

<br><br><br>

<div class="div2">
 <label for="Bike">
     <input id="Bike" type="checkbox"> I have a bike
    </label><br>
   <label for="Car">
     <input id="Car" type="checkbox"> I have a car
    </label><br>
<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey. The ids for the elements are entirely different.